# Calculating Expected Value Given a Discrete Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem**
Given a discrete distribution below, calculate $E[3X]$ and $E[47]$.

[image]
**Question**
So using the taught formula about calculating expected value it comes out looking like this: $$E[X] = -1(\frac{1}{3}) + 0 + 1(\frac{1}{6}) + 2(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}$$
My answer was $\frac{1}{2}$ for both E[3X] and E[47]. Is this correct? My understanding from the formula is that no matter what X is, the average expected value is .5, even if it is $3X$.

Comment: Sorry, What does $E[47]$ mean?  The expected value of a constant is just the constant, but maybe you mean something else.  Also $3X$ surely means "three times $X$", hence the random variable which takes values $\{-3,0,3,6\}$ with probabilities $\{\frac 13,\frac 16,\frac 16,\frac 13\}$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry! Getting a hang on statistics! E[47] then must be 0 since it isn't defined in the table? I understand your answer for $3X$: it was very clear.

Comment: If, by $E[47]$ you mean "the expected value of the variable which equals $47$ with probability $1$" then $E[47]=47$.    Informally, if you always observe the value $47$ then of course the average observed value is $47$.

Comment: @lulu It could be that the question is a trick one at that. I believe it's asking for E[47] given the distribution table. Since E[47] doesn't make sense, should it be 0 then?

Comment: Once again, the only meaning I can see for $E[47]$ is the one I gave:  it is the expected value of the constant variable $47$.  It has nothing to do with $X$.  So, no.  I don't see any way at all to justify the answer $0$.  Think of it this way:  $Y=2X+1$ is a perfectly good random variable, no?   It has expected value $E[Y]=E[2x+1]=E[2x]+E[1]=2E[X]+1$.  In that case, you have no problem with $E[1]=1$, yes?

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.